# How does this code not return undefined and please explain the last else in the function

Tags: javascript

I dont understand how this code doesnt return `undefined` when a number that isnt `0` equals `0` and returns true as even and i especially dont understand the last `else statement` in the function.

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return true;
  else if (n == 1)
    return false;
  else if (n < 0)
    return isEven(-n);
  else
    return isEven(n - 2);
}


console.log(isEven(50));
// → true
console.log(isEven(75));
// → false
console.log(isEven(-1));
// → false
```

Comment: "*a number that isnt 0 equals 0*" - wait, what?

Comment: I just want to note that an `isEven` function can be simply implemented by `n => n % 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the final `else` block is implementing *recursion*.

For any integer *n*, we know these rules:

1. If *n* is 0, *n* is even.
2. If *n* is 1, *n* is not even.
3. If *n* is negative, then *n* is even if and only if *-n* is even.
4. Otherwise, *n* is even if and only if *(n-2)* is even.

For example, checking if -4 is even:

- -4 is less than 0, so -4 is even if +4 is even (rule #3).
- 4 is neither 0 nor 1, so 4 is even if (4-2), or 2, is even (rule #4)
- 2 is neither 0 nor 1, so 2 is even if (2-2), or 0, is even (rule #4).
- 0 is even (rule #1), so 6 is also even.

So, the `isEven()` function is deciding whether an integer is even by reducing the problem a step at a time:

- `isEven(-4)` is the third case, so `isEven(-4)` has the same answer as `isEven(4)`.
- `isEven(4)` doesn't match any of the first three cases, so it must have the same answer as `isEven(2)`.
- `isEven(4)` doesn't match any of the first three cases, so it must have the same answer as `isEven(0)`.
- `isEven(0)` matches the first case, so it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

It's recursive function. It subtracts 2 out of initial number up until it's either 0 meaning it was even or 1 meaning it was odd. it also have ability to check negative numbers by turning them into positive on the first iteration with -n.

To help understand it better, simply choose a value, 10 for instance and go step-by-step on the paper.

Answer (score 0):

The first two if clauses are obvious.

The third one: if it's a negative number, try again with the positive version (i.e. -3 will try again with 3.)

The fourth one: the input is larger than two, try again with the same number minus two.  (i.e. 3 will try again with 1, and therefore ultimately return false.)

So given any number (any integer at least), it'll recurse until it tests either zero or one, and therefore return true or false.